# Anyway to force / override html and get a link to open in a new tab/window?

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure if there is a way, but is it possible to force links to open in a new tab / window if the html does not include it? Possibly not, but thought I would ask!

I am importing data into my site.

The problem is that data contains many links to more information - not a problem and am happy for people to click on the links.

My issue is that if they do, they are gone from my site.

Therefore it would be great if I could ensure they stay on my site and open up a new tab or window with the more info.

I am struggling to add some code, so have included it below as a snippet

```html
<div id="lrep799873847" style="width: 350px;">Data loading....<a href="http://full-time.thefa.com/Index.do?divisionseason=664547402">click here for Premier Division</a><br/><br/><a href="http://www.thefa.com/FULL-TIME">FULL-TIME Home</a></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var lrcode = '799873847'
</script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://full-time.thefa.com/client/api/cs1.js"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery('a[href^="http://"]').attr('target','_blank');

Comment: _I am importing data into my site._ can you put lights on this?

Answer (score 0):

Add `target="_blank"` to anchor tag. It will open the said link in new tab and won't take away users form your site.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://any_url_here.html">Link</a>
```

As you said, you can't do it in HTML, you can  do the same with jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

The above function finds all `a` i.e. links and then attaches the same attribute to them, so they open in new tab. But keep in mind that this would open all links in your page in a new tab. You might not want to do that because it will open *your* site pages in new tab too!

Before long, they will end up with *10 open tabs, all from your site*. This irritates the end-user the most.

For this reason, you should check if the link is external and then add `target="_blank"` to this link!

**Solution**

```
$('a').each(function () {
    if (this.host !== location.host) {
        $(this).attr('target', '_blank')
    }
    else {
       // internal link. Do nothing.
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought the question assumed the HTML couldn't be changed?

Answer (score 0):

If HTML doesn't include it you can do it using jquery as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

`target="_blank"` will force it to open in new tab

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your code

```
$(function(){
    jQuery('a').attr('target','_blank');
})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this is an appropriate answer?

Comment: @remus I am selecting all the links in the page and setting/modifying the attribute target into "_blank" once the document is ready

Answer (score 0):

Set `target` attribute of the HTML anchor element with `_blank`.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your links in javascript, either by appending a `target="_blank"` or registering an onclick event for opening in a popup/new window.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelector('a'), function(link) {
   link.target = '_blank'; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*I am importing data into my site.*

This line makes me think that you have dynamically loaded data on your page. If you do then you might have some ajax method which seems to be obvious.
*<sub>(As you have not posted any code.)</sub>*

*The problem is that data **contains** many links to **more information***

So i suggest you to change/add the `target` attribute to those anchors in the ajax response. Like this:

```
success:function(data){
   $(data).find('a:contains(more)').attr('target', '_blank');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery('a[href^="http://"]').attr('target','_blank');
```